# Car dies immediately when started

Tags: electrical, pontiac

I have a 2003 Pontiac Sunfire.

If I turn the key to 'ON', the electrics turn on.  Lights, radio, fans, the works.  Everything is normal.  If I turn the key to 'START', then the whole car dies.  Everything goes out, lights, fans, dash lights, everything.  Turning it off then back to 'ON', and I get nothing.

If I leave it for a few hours, I can turn it back to ON and get the electronics will turn on.  I've checked the fuses and they're fine.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Does it ever start?  How's the ignition switch? This sounds like an intermittent problem

Comment: It started fine yesterday.  I've never seen something like this before.

Comment: Could you test your battery? A weak battery is another possible cause for what you're seeing.

Comment: Agreed with Zaid, battery is the first thing you check. First check if the clamps are on tightly. If they are, remove them and clean them and the posts with a wire brush. If still nothing, then test the battery itself, it's possibly dead.

Comment: Does the car have an immobilizer?

Comment: @HandyHowie Not likely. 2003 car and sunfire was a very cheap/basic model.

Comment: @rana Many 2003 and older cars do have an immobilizer, not really a valid criterion.

Comment: Thanks for tips.  I'll check those out this evening.  I don't have a specific battery tester, but I do have a multi-meter.  Is there a voltage I should have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your connections at the battery is bad. Your vehicle should most likely be a side post battery. Loosen the battery bolt a little, wiggle the connections, then tighten it back down and see if that helps. Ensure both sides are tight.

Comment: This did it.  I checked the voltage at the terminals, it was wandering all over the place.  I unscrewed the terminals, which I could do by hand.  Checked the voltage, it was fine.  Screwed them down firmly and the car started.  The car started with a rather angry noise, so I hooked it up to my battery charger and left it.  Now it starts with no problems.

Comment: Using the charger to get the charge back up to snuff was a good choice!